# Error: ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: Not a valid libs dir for SikuliX: /Applications/setup/libs

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, selenium-webdriver, sikuli-script

I am trying to run a selenium integrated sikuli java application from mac in Eclipse IDE but it is throwing errors. I have added sikuli script, selenium and chromedriver to /Applications/setup path.

This application is working in windows but seems some issues running on mac os.

Attached is the code and error message, could someone please help me with this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz6CQ.png)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SikuliGameLoad {
@Test
public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed {  
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
"/Applications/setup/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Screen screen = new Screen(); 
Pattern image = new 
Pattern("/Users/name/Documents/workspace/Web/imgs/gmail.png");
screen.wait(image,10);
screen.doubleClick(image);
//screen.click(image3);      

}
}
```

Error:

/Applications/setup/chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b) on port 46875
Only local connections are allowed.
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: Not a valid libs dir for SikuliX (x86_64): /Applications/setup/libs
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: check: libs dir is empty, has wrong content or is outdated
[action] ResourceLoaderBasic: check: Please wait! Trying to extract libs to: /Applications/setup/libs
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: Not a valid libs dir for SikuliX (x86_64): /Applications/setup/libs
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: loadLib: Fatal Error 109: not found: /Applications/setup/libs/libVisionProxy.dylib
[error] Terminating SikuliX after a fatal error(109)! Sorry, but it makes no sense to continue!
If you do not have any idea about the error cause or solution, run again
with a Debug level of 3. You might paste the output to the Q&A board.

Update:

Instead of sikuli script jar I have added sikulixapi.jar and facing below issues:

Exception in thread "main" FindFailed: /Users/name/Documents/workspace/SikuliGameLoad/Images/options.png: (182x56) in S(0)[0,0 1440x900] E:Y, T:3.0
  Line 2754, in file Region.java

```
at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:2754)
at com.sg.test.SikuliGameLoad.SikuliTest.main(SikuliTest.java:26)
```

Comment: Please post the code and the error as text with the appropriate tags.

Comment: I have updated the post with code and error. Thanks.